# Samba 4: Unable to add attribute to LDAP schema

Tags: active-directory, ldap, schema, samba

I am trying to add a new attribute to a group to my existing LDAP/AD Schema. I use Samba 4 as AD Domain Controller. For this I am using a Docker Container which runs samba4.

This is my LDIF File I am trying to import. The OID is constructed and is not present in the current default schema, because I only need to add the attribute to my local dev environment:

```
dn: CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.998877.1.1.998
  NAME 'myNewGroupAttribute'
  DESC 'My New Group Attribute'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128} )
```

I also tried to use the DN of the schema directly:
`CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev`
without a difference.

This is an example from the exported schema of another attribute:

```
dn: CN=Print-Memory,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev
objectClass: attributeSchema
objectClass: top
attributeID: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.282
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.9
cn: Print-Memory
instanceType: 4
isSingleValued: TRUE
lDAPDisplayName: printMemory
objectCategory: CN=Attribute-Schema,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds
 ,DC=dev
oMSyntax: 2
schemaIDGUID:: dF8wuuNH0BGhpgDAT9kwyQ==
adminDescription: Print-Memory
adminDisplayName: Print-Memory
distinguishedName: CN=Print-Memory,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,
 DC=dev
isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet: TRUE
name: Print-Memory
objectGUID:: BQR4WRzt6UakcnVxdpPGgw==
searchFlags: 0
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE
systemFlags: 16
systemOnly: FALSE
uSNChanged: 1249
uSNCreated: 1249
whenChanged: 20230322074448.0Z
whenCreated: 20230322074448.0Z
```

**This is the command I use and the error it throws:**

```
root@ldap:/bin# ldapmodify -x -D "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev" -W -H "ldap://localhost" -f /var/lib/s
amba/private/extensions/filetransferSchema.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
modifying entry "CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev"
ldap_modify: Constraint violation (19)
        additional info: 0000202F: objectclass_attrs: attribute 'attributeTypes' on entry 'CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev' is constructed!
```

*Hint: I copied the .ldif file to the docker container's location before calling the command.*

I don't know what the "is constructed" error means and I didn't find any helpful information on the net.

The logs:

```
2023-06-21 10:01:52 Doing a full scan on CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev and looking for deleted objects
2023-06-21 10:01:53 Doing a full scan on DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev and looking for deleted objects
2023-06-21 10:01:57 {"timestamp": "2023-06-21T08:01:57.714214+0000", "type": "dsdbChange", "dsdbChange": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 0}, "statusCode": 19, "status": "Constraint violation", "operation": "Modify", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:127.0.0.1:38018", "performedAsSystem": false, "userSid": "S-1-5-21-1242627646-2927478795-3490559014-500", "dn": "CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev", "transactionId": "53f18bd5-52ed-4ec8-a80c-d2d0128b9f44", "sessionId": "6598fa77-8536-42a6-bc95-7cec10fde3d8", "attributes": {"attributeTypes": {"actions": [{"action": "add", "values": [{"value": "( 1.2.840.998877.1.1.998 NAME 'myNewGroupAttribute' DESC 'My New Group Attribute' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128} )"}]}]}}}}
2023-06-21 10:01:57 {"timestamp": "2023-06-21T08:01:57.714267+0000", "type": "dsdbTransaction", "dsdbTransaction": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 0}, "action": "rollback", "transactionId": "53f18bd5-52ed-4ec8-a80c-d2d0128b9f44", "duration": 647}}
```

Anyone has a suggestion?

---

FYI (not directly problem-related):

The Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install samba krb5-config winbind smbclient 
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install iproute2
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install openssl
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install vim

RUN rm /etc/krb5.conf
RUN mkdir -p /opt/ad-scripts

WORKDIR /opt/ad-scripts

CMD chmod +x *.sh && ./samba-ad-setup.sh && ./samba-ad-run.sh
```

The scripts:

`samba-ad-setup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

info () {
    echo "[INFO] $@"
}

info "Running setup"

# Check if samba is setup
[ -f /var/lib/samba/.setup ] && info "Already setup..." && exit 0

info "Provisioning domain controller..."

info "Given admin password: ${SMB_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"

rm /etc/samba/smb.conf

samba-tool domain provision\
 --server-role=dc\
 --use-rfc2307\
 --dns-backend=SAMBA_INTERNAL\
 --realm=`hostname`\
 --domain=DEV-AD\
 --adminpass=${SMB_ADMIN_PASSWORD}

touch /var/lib/samba/.setup
```

`samba-ad-run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

[ -f /var/lib/samba/.setup ] || {
    >&2 echo "[ERROR] Samba is not setup yet, which should happen automatically. Look for errors!"
    exit 127
}

samba -i -s /var/lib/samba/private/smb.conf
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
    samba:
        build:
            context: ./docker/samba-ad
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        hostname:
            ldap.ds.dev
        privileged: true
        image: samba/ad
        ports:
            - '389:389'
        environment:
            SMB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: my-admin-password
        volumes:
            - './docker/samba-ad/scripts:/opt/ad-scripts'
            - 'samba:/var/lib/samba'
            - './docker/samba-ad/configs/smb.conf:/var/lib/samba/private/smb.conf'
        networks:
            - samba
networks:
    samba:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    samba:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 1):

"is constructed" means it's a *virtual* attribute – read-only and generated on demand based on some other attributes.

Active Directory does not use the "standard" format for schema definitions and you cannot import OpenLDAP-style schema LDIFs directly. You actually need to mimic the format that you're seeing in the existing attributes.

You only need about half of them, though – quite a few in your export are also constructed or otherwise automatic. See [MS-ADA1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada1/19528560-f41e-4623-a406-dabcfff0660f), [MS-ADA2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada2/e20ebc4e-5285-40ba-b3bd-ffcb81c2783e), [MS-ADA3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada3/4517e835-3ee6-44d4-bb95-a94b6966bfb0) for the attributes involved. Something like this:

```
dn: CN=myNewGroupAttribute,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ldap,DC=ds,DC=dev
objectClass: attributeSchema
lDAPDisplayName: myNewGroupAttribute
adminDisplayName: myNewGroupAttribute
adminDescription: My New Group Attribute
attributeID: 1.2.840.998877.1.1.998
# AD-specific syntax for Unicode string
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
oMSyntax: 64
rangeLower: 1
rangeUpper: 128
isSingleValued: FALSE
searchFlags: 0
```

(I would actually suggest adding schema from Windows, if you have it – `regsvr32.exe schmmgmt.dll` will make the "AD Schema" snap-in available in MMC.)

Keep in mind that Samba requires `dsdb:schema update allowed` to make schema updates possible, *and* you must add yourself to the "Enterprise Admins" or "Schema Admins" group (Domain Admin is not enough).

Comment: The last comment regarding the dsdb privilege is an important one - and hopefully will save others tons of headaches.  If it is not set in smb.conf, any attempt to modify the schema will return "Unwilling to perform"  errors galore.